# PHP 5.4 does not recognize parent constant

Tags: php, php-5.4

I migrated my cloud server, and after install all lamp stuff and clone my repository my php just does not recognizes the 'parent' constant.

My log says.

> [Wed Jul 08 21:29:28 2015] [error] [client 186.223.169.223] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant parent - assumed 'parent' in /home/dev/xxx/Funcionario.php on line 11, referer: xxx

And in code I have

```
class Funcionario extends Model {

    protected function init() {
        $this -> db = DataBase::getInstance('000001');

        call_user_func_array(array( parent, 'init'), func_get_args() );
    }
}
```

Obs. PHP-5.4

Thanks.

Comment: what? why are you calling it that way, just do parent::init(), you have no args to worry about.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Except that `Funcionario::init()` may be called with arguments beyond what's in the declaration; hence the use of `func_get_args()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use of undefined constant parent - assumed 'parent'

This is because `parent` not being followed by the scope operator `::` is considered a constant; it works fine if you make it a string:

```
call_user_func_array(array('parent', 'init'), func_get_args());
```

It works fine without it as well, the only reason why you're seeing that notice now is because of a different `error_reporting` level.

Comment: Thanks. I realised this 15 minutes later, but forgot to answer here.